# Couchbase- How to Update TTL of a collection

Tags: couchbase

Can we update TTL of collection in couchbase at Runtime. In Java springboot? The requirement is to update TTL of entire collection and not for document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to change the max TTL of an existing collection.

A possible workaround would be to create a new collection with the desired TTL, then copy the documents from the old collection to the new one. (Admittedly, this is not something you would do casually at runtime.)